# TreeNodeCollpased and TreeNodeExpanded events in Treeview using css friendly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio, css-friendly

when I use css friendly, TreeNodeCollpased and TreeNodeExpanded events in treeview do not fire. I'm trying to save treeview state in a dictionary and restore the state. Any idea? (li and ul tags have no id)

Comment: Try with BeforeExpand and BeforeCollapse events

Comment: Thank you for reply. But there are no BeforeExpand  and BeforeCollapse  events in asp treeview.